# (x,y) Coordinates for g.drawPolygon(p);

Tags: java, graphics

Code works, not looking for code help, but I am looking for some help with an arbitrary polygon. It can be any shape, and I have been playing around but can't seem to get a star shape. I am asking if anyone has a cool shape with the x,y coordinates so I can get a nice looking shape for my homework assignment. If you would like to see the code that this runs for I can but it is an academic assignment. So the program draws a shape with a counterpoint within the shape, and sends lines given by n value to the border of the shape without going past the borders. Thanks much for any help!!

```
public void drawRangeMap(Graphics g)
{
    //Draw map of room
    //int x[] = polygonX;
    //int y[] = polygonY;
    int [] px = {150,169,256,196,300,196,256,169,150,131,44,104,0,104,44,150,150};
    int [] py = {0,103,44,131,150,169,256,196,300,196,256,169,150,131,44,103,150};
    p = new Polygon(px, py, 14);
    g.drawPolygon(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use some graphics or CAD program to draw the shape, then check the coordinates of the corner points. Most graphics software at least allows you to display the mouse cursor coordinates.

You could also generate a star shape mathematically by calculating points on two concentric circles. Take the points alternately from one of the two circles. Use Math.sin and Math.cos for the calculation.